# Simple collision detection of 2 divs with CSS animation, using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, collision-detection

I'm trying to build out a super simple Super Mario-style game using just HTML, CSS and JS.

I'm not using `<canvas>` just building the whole thing out in simple divs, and getting the movement of the background and characters with CSS Animations.

The part where I'm running into issues is getting collision detection between the character and the monsters. Basically what I want to happen is if the character at all touches the monster, the game is over, and you avoid the monsters by jumping.

I have tried different snippets of JS for div collision detection, but the issue there is the code returns the static X and Y positions of the div, and not that of each keyframe in the CSS animation.

Doing some digging, I found a way for the code to track the X and Y of each keyframe by adding an event listener to my monster and character divs:

```
    shadow1.addEventListener('animationiteration', function (event) {
       shadowDiv = this.getBoundingClientRect();
       console.log(shadowDiv);
    });

    cont.addEventListener('animationiteration', function (event) {
      charDiv = this.getBoundingClientRect();
      console.log(charDiv);
});
```

The above returns all the X and Y positions as the animation is running into the console for both the monster and the character, but the issue I'm running into with this, is that it only returns the keyframes if it's inside the scope of the event listener. I have tried every which way to get the same thing to happen in a global scope, but everytime I do, it returns a value of undefined, and from there I am basically stuck. and not sure how to move forward.

Any help would be appreciated!

Below is the relevant code:

HTML

```
 <div id="char-container"></div>

 <div id="shadow-container-1"> </div>

 <div id="btn"> Jump! </div>
```

CSS

```
@keyframes rtol {
  0% { left: 800px; opacity: 1;}
  80% { opacity: 1;}
  85%{ opacity: 0.75;}
  90% { left: -220px; opacity: 0;}
  100% { left: -220px; opacity: 0;}
}

#shadow-container-1{
 width: 100px;
 height: 160px;
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 bottom: 450px;
 left: 800px;
 opacity: 1;
 animation-name: rtol;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-direction: normal;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
 animation-fill-mode: backwards;

@keyframes jump {
    from { bottom: -50px;  left: 0px; }
    to { bottom: 400px; left: 150px; }
}


#char-container{
 width: 150px;
 height: 200px;
 position: relative;
 bottom: -50px;
}
```

JS

```
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');

let cont = document.getElementById('char-container');


btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){

   if(e.target = btn){
       cont.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = 'running';
       cont.style.webkitAnimation = 'jump 1.25s ease 2';
       cont.style.webkitAnimationDirection = 'alternate';
   }

});

cont.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", function(e){

  cont.style.webkitAnimation = '';
});


let shadow1 = document.getElementById('shadow-container-1');

shadow1.style.webkitAnimationDuration = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 3   + 's';

shadow1.addEventListener('animationiteration', function (event) {
      shadowDiv = this.getBoundingClientRect();
      console.log(shadowDiv);
});


cont.addEventListener('animationiteration', function (event) {
      charDiv = this.getBoundingClientRect();
      console.log(charDiv);
});
```